# Python Pulp error with pyspark: Unsupported Operation Between Types

Tags: python, pyspark, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I have an optimization problem where for each customer I have an FTE column  (number of full time employees) and a profit column. There is a constraint on the number of FTEs and I need to maximize profit.

First I prepare the spark dataframe:

```
US_AEI = (
    US_AEI
    .filter(F.col("Channel")=="A"
    .select("Customer_Name", "ftes", "profit")
    .filter(F.col("profit").isNotNull())
    .filter(F.col("ftes").isNotNull())
    .withColumn("profit_per_fte", F.col("profit")/F.col("ftes"))
    )
```

The FTE column is a double. For example Customer A could have 0.01 FTEs to make 1000 profit.

Then I prepare the lists and dictionaries:

```
  keys = [x.Customer_Name for x in US_AEI.select('Customer_Name').collect()]

values = [x.profit_per_fte for x in US_AEI.select('profit_per_fte').collect()]

profit_per_fte= dict(zip(keys, values))

emp_values = [x.ftes for x in US_AEI.select('ftes').collect()]
ftes = dict(zip(keys, emp_values))
```

Maximum number of FTEs:

```
    fte_envelope = 40
```

Since a customer can be chosen or not chosen to have FTEs, I make it binary:

```
    customer_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Customer",keys,lowBound=0,cat='Binary')
```

Creating the problem and adding the constraint:

```
        prob = LpProblem("Profit", LpMaximize)
    
prob += lpSum([profit_per_fte[i]*customer_vars[i] for i in keys]) 
    
#constraint
    prob += lpSum([ftes[c] * customer_vars[c] for c in keys])<= fte_envelope

prob.solve()
```

At this point I get an error,

> prob += lpSum(profit_per_fte[i]*customer_vars[i] for i in keys) #TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, when I return a dataframe everything looks as expected, the profit and FTE columns are both doubles and they don't have any nulls.

```
pandasDF = pd.DataFrame(keys, columns = ['Customer'])
pandasDF = pandasDF.assign(profit_per_fte = values)
pandasDF = pandasDF.assign(FTEs = emp_values)

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sparkDF=spark.createDataFrame(pandasDF) 


return sparkDF
```

Any suggestions for getting past this error would be greatly appreciated.

The full data has 6 sales channels per customer, as a first step I was trying to get it working with the data filtered for one channel only. For the full data I will also need to add a binary constraint so that a maximum of one sales channel is chosen per customer. Not all customers need ot be assigned an FTE.

This is the logic I've been unable to test because of the previous error, any feedback would be appreciated.

```
channel = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

 #setting the decision variables
 use_vars = LpVariable.dicts("UseChannel", channel, 0, 1, LpBinary)
 chan_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Service", [(i,j) for i in customer,
                                                    for j in channel],
                                                    0)

 prob += lpSum(atcost[j] * use_vars[j] for j in channel)
 prob += lpSum(ftes[i] * customer[i] for i in customer) <= fte_envelope

 prob.sovle
```

Comment: You neglected above to show where & how `customer_vars` is defined, which is what that error message is calling out as the problem...  why don't you put a little print statement in before constructing that constraint to inspect a few values of that array before attempting to construct?

Comment: This is the output for customer vars, I'm not sure why it would be seen as a none type, there are no nulls in the list: {'M LLC': Customer_M_LLC, 'Adv Photography': Customer_Adv_Photography, 'Biomedical Incorporated': Customer_Biomedical_Incorporated, 'Water Company': Customer_Water_Company,

Comment: Create a list of types of the elements of `customer_vars` like so `[type(customer_vars[i]) for i in keys]` and then print that list. I'm fairly confident one of them will be a none type - and you can work back from there to work out why.

Comment: The output of set([type(c) for c in customer_vars]) is {<class 'str'>}. I also checked that there are no empty strings.

Comment: I recommend testing the model without spark. Make a function that takes the input data as arguments and builds the model. Then see if it works with some sample data. If it does, then the issue has something to do with spark. If not, you can check with the data. In any case, debugging will be a lot easier.

Comment: @user99137 - it would be worth checking using the `i in keys` to generate the test list in case there's a missing key (a key that exists in `keys` but not in `customer_vars`). Beyond that I think you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I filtered the data for profit >0 and then it ran. It's not clear to me why it should have been a problem. Seems like the error message was misleading.